# CSS выборка

Tags: css

Доброго времени, уважаемое сообщество! Помогите с css выборкой.

Имеется DOM-ветка:

```
div class="entry"
   p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify;"
   p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify;"
   p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify;"
   p class="postinfo"
```

Вопрос: Как мне отобрать **div class="entry"** со всеми тегами **p class="MsoNormal"**, но без тега **p class="postinfo"**

Дело в том, что я использую вот эту [PHP-библиотеку](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), с ее помощью я собираю инфу с этого [сайта](http://fondbirzha.ru/), буду конкретнее хочу выдергивать новости с главной страницы, потом запихивать их к себе в БД ну и где-то на своем сайте их выводить.

Создал я вот такой код:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://fondbirzha.ru');

        // Ищем названия новостей
        $ID_nameNews = 1;
        foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div h2 a') as $element) {            
            $nameNews = '<div id="nameNews'.$ID_nameNews++.'"><b>Название новости:</b> ' . $element->innertext . '</div><br>';
            echo $nameNews;
        }

        // Ищем дату публикации
        $ID_dateNews = 1;
        foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div div.postdate') as $element) {
            $dateNews = '<div id="dateNews'.$ID_dateNews++.'"><b>Дата публикации:</b> ' . $element->innertext . '</div><br>';
            echo $dateNews;
        }

        // Ищем полное описание новости

        $ID_contentNews = 1;
        foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div div.entry') as $element) {
            $contentNews = '<div id="contentNews'.$ID_contentNews++.'" style="border: 1px solid gray;"><b>Полное описание:</b> ' . $element->outertext . '</div><br>';
            echo $contentNews;
        }
```

---

*Ну и вот на этом [ресурсе](http://xdan.ru/Uchimsya-parsit-saity-s-bibliotekoi-PHP-Simple-HTML-DOM-Parser.html) я нашел что-то связанное с вызовом обратной функции:*

```
function my_callback($element) {
       if ($element->tag=='span')
                $element->outertext = '<b>'.$element->innertext. '</b>';// заменим все span элементы на b
} 
$html  = str_get_html('<span>bar</span><span>pole</span><span>sushi</span><a>okno</a>');
// Регистрация функции обратного вызова с ее именем
$html->set_callback('my_callback');// вызов функции произойдет при конвертации объекта в строку
echo $html; // на самом деле, при этом вызывается магический метод __toString, он и запускает наши калбяки
```

---

*Также думал на счет использования функции* **preg_match()** *для такой вот строки (но немогу правильно составить регулярку):*

```
<p class="postinfo">
<a href="http://fondbirzha.ru/post/5062#comments" title="Комментарий на Накопившиеся плюсы позволят краткосрочно сыграть наверх.">3 Комментариев »</a><br>
Опубликовано в : <a href="http://fondbirzha.ru/category/news" title="Просмотреть все записи в Новости" rel="category tag">Новости</a></p>
```

---

---

НАРОД ВСЕМ СПАСИБО ЗА УЧАСТИЕ!!! Сам разобрался! Ниже написал решение если кому интересно:

```
// очищаем страницу от не нужного мне тега p.postinfo
foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div div.entry p.postinfo') as $tmp)$tmp->outertext = '';

// и теперь находим мой DIV
if(count($html->find('div.narrow_column div div.entry'))){
    // Ищем полное описание новости
    $ID_contentNews = 1;
    foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div div.entry') as $element) {

        $contentNews = '<div id="contentNews'.$ID_contentNews++.'" style="border: 1px solid gray;"><b>Полное описание:</b> ' . $element->outertext . '</div><br>';
        echo $contentNews;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите исключить **div class="entry"**, в котором есть дочерний **p class="postinfo"**, но присутствует **p class="MsoNormal"**? Тогда одними css-средствами тут не обойтись.

Comment: нет, нет, я наоборот хочу исключить**p class="postinfo"**, а все остальное оставить как есть

Comment: @Deonis я дополнил свой вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста!

Comment: ВСЁЁЁ Сделал!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выбираем все элементы p c классом MsoNormal в div с классом entry:

```
div.entry p.MsoNormal { ... }
```

Comment: Дополнил свой вопрос!

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите `:not` селектор

Comment: а напишите пример, пожалуйста!